# SQL - WHERE MATCH query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have SQL query -

```
SELECT id, text FROM some_table WHERE  MATCH (text, keywords) AGAINST ('".$search."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I'm not quite understand the difference between "IN BOOLEAN MODE" and "IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE".

I tried to read about it but still not get it.

Can you please explain it to me and maybe provide an example?

Comment: Please provide a more specific question.  The MySQL documentation devotes a lot of effort to making this clear.  If there is something in particular that you don't understand, ask about that.

Comment: It give you the possibility to add operator on searched words
Ex: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean-text-searches.aspx
What do you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read it in the mySQL docs:
Fulltext boolean mode:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Fulltext natural language Mode:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

In summary, the boolean mode uses the + and - operators and is more 'strict'.
Natural language mode returns the most 'relevant' rows according to your search.

Comment: thanks. so if i have a search form for FAQ, will it be better if i'll use "IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE" ?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer Natural Language mode in FAQ search. Please confirm by clicking the check mark if this is the answer that solved your problem.